# Differentiation rule for $A(x)x$ with $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the differentiation rule for $Ax$ is as follows

$d(Ax)/dx$ = $x$ where $A$ is a matrix and $x$ is a vector.

But what is the differentiation rule for $A(x)x$ with $x$.

$A$ is a function of vector $x$

By my intuition is seems like below

$d(A(x)x)/dx = dA(x)/dx*x + A $

Could somebody help with to verify if my intuition is correct and can provide proof if is correct for the same(if it is correct).

Comment: It is not true that the derivative of the $x\mapsto Ax$ is the identity (at least that seems to be what you are suggesting).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Appears to be a typo..?

Comment: The total differential of $x\mapsto Ax$ is given by $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems right, but you need to take care: you are taking derivative of a vector as a function of a vector. This means the result is a matrix.

There is some subtlety with the notation $\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dx}$. Using indices, $A_{ij}$ is the $i$-th row, $j$-th column of the matrix $A$. Then $$(\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dx})_{ijk} = \frac{\mathrm{d}A_{ij}}{\mathrm{d}x_k}$$ has three indices! This is best described with what is called **tensors**.

Refer to your textbook for more information, or ask a new question about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, you are correct about the 3 indices, this particular term is a 3rd Order Tensor. Though could you provide any proof for the intuition equation I had written. I do not seem to find any particular literature about it.